# Is there a way to have a symbolic link or an alias for a database schema in AWS RDS Aurora?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

On an Aurora instance, is it possible to have a symbolic link so that every call for a certain schema is redirected to another one? For example, if I have a schema named Foo and I want every statement made to the schema Bar to be redirected on Foo. Bar does exist, but I don't want it to be called.

Comment: *"Bar does exist, but I don't want it to be called."*  What is the motivation for this and what would it accomplish for you?

Comment: I want to move some tables from Bar to Foo. I would add triggers between them, then copy all content. Last step before deploying new code that points to Foo would be to add the symbolic link so that all writes are made on Foo from now on.

Comment: Just revoke access to Bar. Making an alias is asking for trouble, and you can't create a view to do this kind of task.

Comment: If I revoke access I am causing a down time while doing the code rotation, old code is going to call Bar and it is going to be denied. This is inacceptable for me, I want no downtime or read only period.